# How do you fill an array with strings in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to fill an array with names from a file:

```
Andrew
Andy
Bob
Dan
Derek
Joe
Pete
Richy
Steve
Tyler
```

Here is the function I wrote...but the program crashes when I run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  int i=0, size=10;
  char fname[15];
  char** data;
  char* name;
  FILE* fp;

  printf("Enter a filename to read names:\n");
  scanf("%s", fname);

  fp = fopen(fname, "r");
  if(fp == NULL)
    exit();

  data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**)*size);

  while(!feof(fp)){
    fscanf(fp, "%s", name);
    data[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(name));
    data[i] = name;
    i++;
  }

  fclose(fp);

  printf("\n\n");

  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("%s ", data[i]);

  free(data);
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of errors here:

1) You never allocate memory where `name` will get stored.  You could get around this simply by using:

```
char name[128];
```

Then, when you use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/), you'd have:

```
fscanf(fp, "%127s", name); // stores this in name correctly, now...
```

2) You're inappropriately allocating space for `data[i]`:

```
data[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(name));
```

This will allocate space to hold one **pointer to char** (`char*`), since name is a `char*`.  You need to be doing:

```
data[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name) + 1 ) );
```

This will allocate enough space for the data plus a single terminating character.

3) You aren't assigning `data[i]` correctly.  You can't just use `=` here, but need to use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/):

```
strcpy(data[i], name);
```

4) You're not freeing the individual pointers in the `data[..]` elements.  You should add, after your printf, a free:

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", data[i]);
    free(data[i]);  // Free each pointer you allocate
}
```

Every `malloc` call should eventually have a matching `free` call.

Comment: Reed, I'm not going to downvote because you answered succintly and correctly, but you aren't helping him when you don't make him think about the process.

Comment: Great thanks a lot, it is working now. And yes I now understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @San Jacinto: I don't know - I felt like this was clear,but not just rewriting all of his code.  Hard to help without pointing out why things are flaws... but I do see your point.  @Andrew: I'm glad it's working, and you understand it now.

Answer (score 5):

You never allocate space for name.  But you put stuff in on this line:

```
 fscanf(fp, "%s", name);
```

change

```
 char name[100];
```

and

```
fscanf(fp, "%99s", name);
```

you should limit the imput to filename too:

```
scanf("%14s", fname);
```

also you never free the data for each element in the array, if this were a sub-routine in a larger system it would have a memory leak.

Comment: Oh...but how do I know how much space to allocate if I don't know how long the name is going to be? Do I have to scan characters on every line and count?

Comment: you should have a line length limit; create a buffer and scan into it - the rest will be truncated. If you want an endlessly long lines possible, you should dynamically reallocate the buffer until everything is read. 
Then allocate exactly the number of bytes in the name (+1) and strncpy the name into it.

Comment: I alway just made a really big buffer.  But you can scan first and count if you want.  For a homework assignment you can just make a big buffer IMHO

Comment: Ok, now the program doesn't crash...but when I print it prints Tyler Tyler Tyler...10 times.

Comment: right you have to allocate space for name in data and do a strcpy not an assignment.  see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241834/why-is-my-char-writable-and-sometimes-read-only-in-c/2241876#2241876

Comment: @kibitzer good thing I don't program in C. This doesn't look like much more fun than counting 1s and 0s.

Comment: @Andrew: See my point 3 - that's why you're getting "Tyler Tyler Tyler"...  The way you have it written, you're just setting EVERY data[i] to point to (the same) "name", which is going to be filled with "Tyler" at the end.

Comment: @orokusaki we are all glad you don't program in C too. :D

Comment: @Hogan I only take high paying jobs.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems.  Other answer talk about name not being initialized, so I won't repeat that.

A second problem is that you are not handling EOF correctly.  feof will only return true once you've tried to read just past the end of the file.  So you will get an empty 11'th name.

A final problem is that the data array can only hold 10 names.  Because of the second problem you'll overflow the buffer with the blank 11'th name.  Furthermore, your code depends on the details of the input file - give it a different input file with more names and you'll still crash even after fixing problem 2.